# How can I get the video for a video message I sent on Skype?

Tags: video, skype

I'm using Skype 6.3 on OSX 10.6.

Is there any way I can get to the video file of a video message that I sent?

Comment: What have you researched and/or tried so far?

Comment: Looked through `~/Library/Application\ Support/Skype/` (couldn't find a file that looks like a video file) and tried to see if my sent messages are available at skype.com (they're not, at least not as far as I could find).